# JMeter: NoClassDefFoundError error when used jackson jar

Tags: java, jmeter, noclassdeffounderror, jackson-databind

I'm creating a custom Java sampler in JMeter. It's working just fine. However, when I wanted it to return a result in JSON, JMeter didn't found the .jar for the jackson-databind library, which is needed for the creation of the JSON.

I put it to the /lib/ext folder in the JMeter main directory. I also copied to /lib, to no avail. (I know that /lib/ext shouldn't be used for dependency jars, but JMeter doesn't find my utility jars in /lib in my experience.)

I tried adding the path to the variables search_paths, user.classpath and plugin_dependency_paths in jmeter.properties. I tried with absolute path, relative path, with slash, with backslash, but neither helped.

I tried setting the JMETER_HOME variable to the address of my installation. It worked, yet it didn't help.

I tried running in two environments. The first is within Eclipse (I copied JMeter to a workspace folder, then imported the project), with JMeter 4.0. I got this error in the log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at (creating ObjectMapper here)
    at (creating ResponseJSON here)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:197) ~[ApacheJMeter_java.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
```

I also ran JMeter 3.3 from the .bat file, adding the jars to the same place. I got this error on the console:

```
Unknown error checking for existence of class: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Versioned
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.loadClass(LoaderUtil.java:141)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.isClassAvailable(LoaderUtil.java:115)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Loader.isClassAvailable(Loader.java:310)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.yaml.YamlConfigurationFactory.<init>(YamlConfigurationFactory.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.ReflectionUtil.instantiate(ReflectionUtil.java:188)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.addFactory(ConfigurationFactory.java:190)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getInstance(ConfigurationFactory.java:164)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:613)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.<clinit>(JMeter.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:246)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 43 more
```

I didn't try to debug the classloader, but probably that'll be the next step when I finished posting it here.

I have this version of the file, same as in my POM:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of [jackson-databind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.1.4) dependencies is specifically jackson-core jar you are probably missing and include missing class in your error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned`

See [Jackson Installation](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-installation.html):

> The three JAR files (projects) in the Jackson JSON API are:
>
> - Jackson Core
> - Jackson Annotations
> - Jackson Databind

Comment: Good point. I didn't know before that I need to check compile depencencies on that page. But unfortunately, that didn't help either (I added the jars then restarted Eclipse before running JMeter).

Comment: The jackson-annotations wasn't in the build path of the Eclipse project the last time I checked. Now I added it the build path and finally it works! But I thought it wouldn't make a difference since the jar is read from inside the program anyways. Do you know why is it so?

Comment: @GregT you see in exception jackson databind trying to load using reflection a class found in its dependency jar

Comment: It would have helped if I had the JMeter in a Maven project, but alas, only the Java Sampler were (and I edited the wrong POM).

Comment: @GregT see https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md